# Maven 2 mysteriously showing up in $PATH

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I'm upgrading to maven 3 but have hit a small snag in that maven 2 is mysteriously showing up in my `PATH` variable. I've checked `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile` and can't find it anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install both versions locally? whats the output of `echo "$PATH"` ? how did you find it in your path?

Comment: /home/elpinguino/scala-2.10.5/bin:/home/elpinguino/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin:/bin:/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin

Comment: well that sums up the answer..you have installed both locally....you have two options 1)you can either remove the maven-2 installation directory completely by `sudo rm -r /opt/apache-maven-2.2.1` or 2)remove `/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin` from `PATH`. Which one do you want?

Comment: Ideally both. I wish I could find where I was setting /opt/apache-maven-2.2.1 in my path.

Comment: You mean the file where you have put the `PATH`?

Comment: Yeah. For what it's worth removing the old maven 2 fixes the issue but somewhere out there a file is adding it to the PATH. The files I listed above do not contain this addition.

Comment: Do you have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`. If so , check them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23554/discussion-between-chris-and-heemayl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter‐
>   active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
>   mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading
>   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and
>   ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the
>   first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be
>   used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if
>   these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.
>   The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands
>   from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

As you have logged into an interactive non-login shell, the files to look for the `PATH` assignment is `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` and also in `/etc/environment` as its the default place to declare system wide environment variables. You should also check the directories that are sourced while logging into an interactive login shell to be sure that there is no reference or pointer to change `PATH` in them.

If you does not find any reference to `PATH` having `maven-2` then there must be something in one of these files that is causing the `PATH` to be changed i.e. something in one of these files triggering something else that is changing the `PATH`. It is very hard to tell without checking the content of the files.

If you want to remove `maven-2` from your `PATH`:

```
/home/elpinguino/scala-2.10.5/bin:/home/elpinguino/bin:/usr/local/sbin
:/usr/loca‌​l/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
:/opt/apache-maven‌​-2.2.1/bin:/bin:/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
```

You can either remove the directory `/opt/apache-maven‌​-2.2.1` so that `PATH` won't find the executable or declare `PATH` environment variable again discarding the `/opt/apache-maven‌​-2.2.1/bin` directory and putting it at the end of `~/.bashrc`.