# The $PATH added to .bash_profile is not working after reboot

Tags: environment-variables

I am new to Ubuntu!
And I am trying to setup manually Maven by adding Maven directory into `$PATH`. I created `.bash_profile` file in my `home` directory. The file contains this:

```
export PATH=/opt/devel/tools/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:$PATH
```

And then on a terminal, I run

```
source .bash_profile
```

Everything works fine and I can see the version after running `mvn -version`. But after rebooting laptop, running `mvn` gets the following error:

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Could you tell me what I am missing please? Any help would be appropriate!

**Edit 1**
The output of `echo $PATH` is:

```
tuandang@Inspiron-N4030:~$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Check this thread [$PATH](http://askubuntu.com/questions/620797/maven-2-mysteriously-showing-up-in-path).

Comment: Thank you! But my case hasn't maven 2 setting up before

Comment: Also add `cat ~/.bash_profile`. Where did you create it? It is not /home. It is /home/$USER

Comment: @Pilot6 It's in home directory. The command shows that `export PATH="/opt/devel/tools/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Add it to ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile

Comment: It does not work in .bash_profile for me either. I will look at it later to find out why.

Comment: .bash_profile is used when login in via console not using terminal, you have to use .bashrc instead. check my asnwer.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've already tried with `~/.profile` but no luck :(. Thank you in advanced, please update your answer if you find out why :)

Comment: @Maythux You are right. it's working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First Please note that adding envs to the `.bash_profile` is not a temporary as indicated in other answer, but your problem is adding in non-suitable place since `.bash_profile` is called when you login from console which I don't think your case. Please Read the rest and find your solution:

Quoted from http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html:

> When you login (type username and password) via console, either
>   sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: .bash_profile is executed
>   to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.
>
> But, if
>   you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new terminal window
>   (xterm) inside Gnome or KDE, then .bashrc is executed before the
>   window command prompt. .bashrc is also run when you start a new bash
>   instance by typing /bin/bash in a terminal.

So as I suppose you logged in and use the terminal from inside then you should use the .bashrc instead. run this command:

```
echo 'export PATH=/opt/devel/tools/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bashrc
```

Then source it:

```
source .bashrc
```

For more information please read [this](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile)

If you want your variables to be used in .bash_profile also you can do this trick. Add all of your variables in `.bashrc` then source it from `.bash_profile`. Add this to your `bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Now when you login to your system whenever it's from a console or GUI you'll get your environment.

Comment: [Environmental variables have no business being set in `~/.bashrc`.](http://superuser.com/a/183956/151431)

Answer (score 2):

You can add your PATH to ~/.profile

~./bash_profile does not affect terminal emulators, like gnome-terminal, that are started after you log into system.

As an option you can setup PATH in /etc/environment globally.

Comment: Thanks for detail guide. I tried with `/etc/environment` before and it worked. But now I want to set with `~/.bash_profile`. My desktop in office also set in `.bash_profile`file and it's working. So I don't think the PATH only is temporarily

Comment: You are correct. I missed that you added to .bash_profile. I saw only export command. Why don't you add to your question output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: -1 .bash_profile is not temporary.

Comment: @Maythux You are correct. I first overlooked it, then forgot to edit ))

Comment: ok -1 removed then

Answer (score 1):

Maythux is correct, the variable was declared local, but for it to be seen as a global variable by the system it would have to be exported.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then 
    . ~/.bashrc 
fi
```

Also works in .bash_profile to source $HOME/.bashrc

Comment: A word of warning: when you start sourcing these numerous rc/profile files from one another madness ensues. Do the research and get things in the correct files. You'll be glad you did later. Nothing worse than finding your path containing the same routes multiple times.