# Environment Variable seems to be set yet not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables, bashrc

I use Ubuntu 14.10 with bash shell.

I downloaded a `gradle` distribution and moved it to a new directory.
I want to permanently set a environment variable to point to the `bin` sub-directory of the gradle folder.

I have edited `~/.bashrc` and `~./profile` according to recommendations to include the path to the gradle's running script. Yet when I type `gradle` (which is the name of the script in the bin folder) it does not run.
Logged out, rebooted and everything but still it does not work.

Is there something I am missing here?

1. added this line on the end of `.bashrc`

   export GRADLE=/home/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin
2. My `~/.profile` file's contents are these:

   ```
   # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
   # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
   # exists.
   # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
   # the files are located in the bash-doc package.

   # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
   # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
   #umask 022

   # if running bash
   if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
       # include .bashrc if it exists
       if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
       . "$HOME/.bashrc"
       fi
   fi

   # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
   if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
       PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin"
   fi

   gradle="$HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin"
   export gradle
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to do `gradle="..."`. That simply creates a variable called `gradle` and is irrelevant (unless that variable is somehow used by `gradle` but you haven't said so). What you want to do is add the directory containing the `gradle` executable to the list of directories your system searches through when trying to find programs to run. This is what the `PATH` variable does.

It is also important not to overwrite the existing contents of `PATH`. So, to add `foo` to the `PATH`, you do:

```
PATH:"$PATH":foo
```

And not

```
PATH="foo"
```

The latter will remove everything from `PATH` and replace it with `foo` alone.

So, combining all this, you want to add the following lines to your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if that exists, but **not** to your `~/.bashrc`):

```
PATH:"$PATH:$HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin"
```

---

Why `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` and not `~/.bashrc`? First of all, because that's what profile is for. More importantly, `~/.bashrc` is read each time you start a new shell. So, for example, each time you open a new terminal. Setting environmental variables that only need to be set once in that file, makes them be reset each time you open a terminal and that's just needless overhead.

Additionally, settings in `~/.bashrc` only affect programs launched from the commandline. If you launch something using the GUI ( a menu entry or a `.desktop` file, for example) those variables will not be available there.

In many systems, including Ubuntu, `~/.profile` is read when you log in graphically. Variables set in that file will therefore be available to GUI programs as well. Also, setting these variables in `~/.profile` is preferred since that file is only read once: at login.

Additionally, this will work even if you change your shell to something other than bash, since `~/.profile` is read by many of the most popular shells.

**Important** : If a `~/.bash_profile` exists, that will be read instead of `~/.profile`. So, if you do have such a file, use that one instead. My recommendation is, if you have a `~/.bash_profile`, to simply delete it and add anything that was there to your standard `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

First you should ensure that your script has execute permissions:

```
chmod +x $HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin/gradle
```

You may need to use `sudo` to do the chmod above..

Now what you miss, when you call `gradle` you are using the environment variable [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

> PATH is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like
>   operating systems that tells the shell which directories to search for
>   executable files

Even though you add the path to $PATH you did it in the .profile while you have to do it in the `.bashrc`.

#### So why .bashrc and not .profile?

please take a look for my answer https://askubuntu.com/a/633820/150504

Now back to solution:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Add the line:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin
```

Now save and exit then source it

```
source .bashrc
```

Now test it.

---

#### Urgent Update:

> PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin"

This would distort your PATH, and you can't use any command in /bin,/usr/bin,... since like that you just override your PATH and set it only to two dirs $HOME/bin and $HOME/sanctus/Documents/Development/gradle-2.2/bin.
Remove this line from your .profile.

test if it affects your syste,

```
echo $PATH
```

result should be(maybe slightly differs):

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

If it's not you should resolve the problem. Add this to your .profile

```
$PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: No, `.bashrc` is not the right place to set environmental variables. That's precisely what `~/.profile` is for. See my answer and [here](http://superuser.com/a/183956/151431).